Sign of a complex integral
If one consider the complex value function
$$
f(z)=\frac{1}{(z-1)^{3/2}(z-2)^{3/2}}
$$
with branch cut chosen to be between $z=1$ and $z=2$.
Consider
$$
\oint f(z) dz,
$$
where the contour is taken to be a circle in the complex plane that contains $z=1,2$.
Could someone explain how do we prove that with this branch cut, the integral is positive. I did it like this but it is very informal: choose the branch of the square roots so that is $z$ is close to the real axis between $z=1$ and $z=2$, then the square roots of $z-1$ and $z-2$ have a positive real part. Then the "top" part of the integral (top half of the circle) has positive real part. Since the bottom part is the complex conjugate, they add up to a real positive quantity. I am not interested in the explicit formulas. I am interested into why this is true. Because this is a toy example of my integrals and I want to understand how I can claim my integrals are positive.

There are $\infty$ ways to choose the branch-cuts. I like to take the principal branch for $\left(z - 1\right)^{3/2}$ and $\left[2^{+},\infty\right)$ for the other one while ${\cal C} = \left{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid   \left\vert z\right\vert = 2^{+} \right}$
